# Get object in array with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a function with a rather convoluted object in this format:

```
function getNBATeamsESPNByAbbrev(abbrev)
{
    var json = {
   "sports":[
      {
         "name":"basketball",
         "id":40,
         "uid":"s:40",
         "leagues":[
            {
               "name":"National Basketball Assoc.",
               "abbreviation":"nba",
               "id":46,
               "uid":"s:40~l:46",
               "groupId":7,
               "shortName":"NBA",
               "teams":[
                  {
                     "id":1,
                     "uid":"s:40~l:46~t:1",
                     "location":"Atlanta",
                     "name":"Hawks",
                     "abbreviation":"ATL",
                  },
                  {
                     "id":2,
                     "uid":"s:40~l:46~t:2",
                     "location":"Boston",
                     "name":"Celtics",
                     "abbreviation":"BOS",
                     "color":"006532", 
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "resultsOffset":0,
   "resultsLimit":50,
   "resultsCount":30,
   "timestamp":"2014-03-22T23:42:43Z",
   "status":"success"
    }   

    obj = _.find(json.sports[0].leagues[0].teams, function(obj) { return obj.abbreviation == abbrev })
    if (obj !== undefined)
    {   
        var team = new Object();
        team.abbrev = abbrev;
        team.location = obj.location;
        team.nickname = obj.name;

                return team;
    }
```

}

It can be easier seen at this [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49L2V/). So I have the team abbreviation, and I want to pull back the team object as a whole (this is a stripped down version, leaving only the necessary details). This seems to work fine. However, another case has arisen, one in which I need to pull back the team object based on its `location + " " + name`. So I tried to do the same thing using underscore.js, passing in the parameter `name`, and changing the predicate in `._find` to `return obj.location + " " + obj.name == name`. For example, I'd pass in `Atalnta Hawks` as `name` and expect to return the relevant team object. Here's a very similar [JSFiddle demonstrating the change](http://jsfiddle.net/49L2V/3/). But, now it can't seem to find the team object I want to pull. Is it because such a string concatenation isn't allowed in underscore.js, or is there something stupid I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 50, you have:

```
team.abbrev = obj.abbrev;
```

and it should be

```
team.abbrev = obj.abbreviation;
```